# Implementing generic Java interface with unknown type as a return type

Tags: java, generics

I'm working with a Java interface defined as:

```
interface Whatever<T> {
    T aMethod();
}
```

I want to implement it for a type that is unknown at compile time (e.g. decided at runtime with reflection). This is possible, because generic types are discarded at compile time, so they are clearly not needed. However, the syntax requires to indicate something to replace for T, or the program will not compile.

What type should I replace for T?

Comment: While I was writing the question, I thought of two solutions, which I posted. Any additional solutions or considerations are welcome.

Comment: Don't use Hungarian notation in java. i.e. don't start your interfaces with I. It's a terrible approach to coding that most of the industry has veered away from now and which is strongly disliked by the java community.

Comment: @SoftwareEngineer Hungarian notation is the convention of choice of the project I'm working on and that gave rise to the question. I changed it for the sake of it, however I don't think it's much related to the question.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to substitute `Object`:

```
Whatever<?> whatever = new Whatever<Object>() {
    public Object aMethod() { [statements] }
};
```

(The `?` type in the variable declaration is just a stylistic device to indicate that we don't really care about the generic type, we could have put `Object` there as well.)

Another solution is to use a lambda:

```
Whatever<?> whatever = () -> { [statements] };
```

Lambdas infer types automatically, and in this case it is perfectly fine because the type does not matter (internally, the compiler probably infers `T` as `Object` or as the type of the object you return in the lambda body).

Comment: `IWhatever` is a raw type. Don't use raw types. Use `IWhatever<?>`.

Comment: @AndyTurner Typing mistake. Corrected.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to implement it for a type that is unknown at compile time (e.g. decided at runtime with reflection)

Generics are purely a compile-time concept. If you don't want or need to know the type at compile-time, don't use generics:

```java
interface Whatever {
    Object aMethod();
}
```

Then it's easier to use:

```java
Whatever whatever = () -> { [statements] };
```

(This is no longer a raw type because it's not generic)

Comment: I do not control the interface.

Comment: I slightly changed the wording of the original question to make that more obvioius. By the way, the interface (minus the changed names, of course) is part of a very big project from a big tech.